# MVC 4 best way of saving child entity?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Being a newbie to MVC, I'm not sure whats the best way of saving a child entity in MVC 4
I have a simple model a Parent have one to many children.

I can create a parent entity - no problems, then return to parents index view. 
From here I have a link i.e.:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Child", "Create","ChildEvent",new{customerId=item.ParentId},"")
```

which takes to the child's Create view.

when I save the child obviously it has to link back to the parent.
Whats the best way of doing this?

- Attach to parent as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573197/mvc3-how-to-link-a-newly-created-child-object-to-its-parent)

Or

- Populate parentId in child entity and save as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888452/is-there-a-better-way-to-add-a-child-record-using-mvc-4-and-entity-framework-5)

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Use hidden field to store the parent id.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC but is just about Entity Framework. The answer is: it's up to you, you can use either approach. See [Entity Framework Relationships & Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx), especially "Creating and Modifying Relationships".

Comment: Thanks for the link, Just wanted to know if there was a preferred way of doing it. I guess both are ok!